# Find conditional expectation from two independent random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given $Y$ is a poisson random variable with mean $\theta$: $P(Y = y) = \frac{\theta^y}{y!}e^{-\theta} , y \in [0, 1, 2, 3...]$.

Moreover, $Var(Y) = \theta$ and $X = Y + Z$ where $Z$ is Bernoulli random variable with expectation $\frac{1}{2}$. $P(Z = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(Z = 0) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $Z$ is independent of $Y$. I need to find $E[X^2\mid Y]$.

I tried to solve this problem using convolution of p.m.f since I known $Y$ and $Z$ are independent and have their corresponding p.m.f. But I can only find p.m.f of $X$ and this does not seem to help me find the conditional expectation. Any ideas?

Comment: can you write the formula for conditional expectation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$E\,[X^2\mid Y=y]=E\,[(Y+Z)^2\mid Y=y]=g(y)\quad,(\text{say})$$

By linearity of expectation,

$$g(y)=E\,[Y^2\mid Y=y]+E\,[2YZ\mid Y=y]+E\,[Z^2\mid Y=y]$$

Knowing that $Z$ (and any function of $Z$) is independent of $Y$, the above can be simplified.

Your final answer is $g(Y)$.

Comment: Thanks for hint. I expand the square and got $E[X^2|Y = y] = E[(y + Z)^2|Y = y] = E[y^2 + 2Zy + Z^2 | Y = y]$ and since Independence I have $E[y^2 + 2Zy + Z^2]$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Since $Y^2+2ZY+Z^2$ is not independent of $Y$, you cannot drop the condition on $Y$. Only $Z$ is independent of $Y$. Linearity of expectation gives $E[y^2\mid Y=y]+E[2Zy\mid Y=y]+E[Z^2\mid Y=y]$. Now continue.

Comment: Z is independent of Y. Can I say $Z^2$ is independent of Y?

Comment: Yes, any function of $Z$ is independent of $Y$. In this particular case you can say $P(Z^2=j\mid Y=y)=P(Z=\sqrt j\mid Y=y)=P(Z=\sqrt j)$ for all $j\in\{0,1\}$.